# Event driven file copy with Google Cloud Functions Node JS to different google bucket

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have file.txt and the following directory structure in two separate Google buckets:

bucket-a/folder-1/folder-a

bucket-a/folder-2/folder-b

bucket-a/folder-3/folder-c

bucket-b
 (has no sub folders)

So far my function looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path');

exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {

  const gcsEvent = event;
  const sourceFilePath = path.format(gcsEvent)
  const sourceFileOnly = path.basename(sourceFilePath)
  const sourcePathOnly = path.dirname(sourceFilePath)
  const sourceFolder = path.basename(path.dirname(sourceFilePath))
  const destFilePath = path.join('bucket-b' , sourceFolder , sourceFileOnly)

  console.log(`Processing file: ${destFilePath}`);
};
```

If file.txt is uploaded to bucket-a/folder-2/folder-b and it doesn't already exist in the destination bucket, I'd like to copy it to destFilePath of bucket-b.
I just can't fathom how to copy the file triggering the event in the first place nor work out how to set the destination to the new file path and bucket which would be:

bucket-b/folder-b/file.txt

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you want to copy the GCS object or move the GCS object from one bucket/folder to the other?

Comment: Thanks Kolban, I need to keep it in the source bucket so copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, moving an object is not possible in Cloud Storage. Even if some library implement `move` or `rename` operation the underlying API calls are `copy` then `delete`.

For copying an object, you have example in several languages [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy).

Don't worry about the existence or not of the folder. Do you want a secret? Folder doesn't exist in Cloud Storage. The path is simply a metadata of the file and help the "human" to better organise the objects. So, feel free to set the path that you want even if it doesn't exist.

Finally, for getting the right folder according with your source file, you have to play with string splitting and substring.

**UPDATE**

My code is working. I stick to your requirement, **but it's not safe if the file is drop to the root of the bucket!**

Here the index.js

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {
  const storage = new Storage();
  const gcsEvent = event;
  const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
  const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name
  const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) //Keep only the file name and the last folder name in the path. Not safe!!

  storage
  .bucket(sourceFileBucket)
  .file(sourcePathOnly)
  .copy(storage.bucket('<Bucket dest>').file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + sourceFolder[1])); //this is not safe!!

};
```

And the package.json

```
 {
    "name": "my_package",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies" : { 
      "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.1.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. Yes copying the file is what I was after as I want to keep a version in the source bucket. Unfortunately I've tried to implement the code in your link but it gives me the following error when I try to deploy it:   Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message:                                                                     Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /srv/index.js:16
await storage
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
 ...

Comment: Delete the `await`. Not sure that you need an asynchronous processing in this case.

Comment: If I delete await so it looks like this: 
storage
  .bucket(sourceBucketName)
  .file(sourceFileOnly)
  .copy(storage.bucket(destBucketName).file(destFileOnly));                                          I get "storage is not defined"

Comment: If on the other hand I add: const storage = new Storage();                                         
I get: "Storage is not a constructor at ..."

Comment: I tested it and it's working on my side. I shared the code

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, Unfortunately I'm still getting the "TypeError: Storage is not a constructor at exports.helloGCS" error. Also sorry to ask a dumb question but why do you say sourceFolder isn't safe?  Source files will never be put in the root dir if that's the reason?

Comment: I rely on a path with `folder/file` with my array access [0] and [1]. If you are at the bucket root, there is an array of 1 index, and error! About your error, have you the dependency in the package? It's strange...

Comment: Still isn't working for me and my package.json is identical to yours. Am I missing something? and no, I never plan on having a file dropped in the root so that should be fine, right?

Comment: How do you deploy your function? If the code work for me, it should work for you...

Comment: Not sure why. Function is a triggered by a Cloud Storage finalise/create event in the Cloud Functions setup. I know this trigger works as I've used it successfully to output to console log.

Comment: Also not sure why I asked, it's just very strange that doesn't work on your side. I just try to find what can be different between our 2 environments! I used the `--runtime=nodejs10` on my side.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Guillaume. I've added a follow on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816199/event-driven-file-copy-from-only-specific-bucket-directory-with-google-cloud-fun) if you're interested: