# Event driven file copy from only specific bucket directory with Google Cloud Functions Node JS 10

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I've had help getting an event driven Google Cloud Function ( Node JS 10 ) to copy files into another Google Cloud Storage bucket and would like to take this slightly further.

I need to filter these trigger files to ONLY copy files from one folder and its sub-directories and NOT any file in the entire bucket.

So for the avoidance of doubt, if I have:

bucket-a/folder-1/folder-a/folder-x

bucket-a/folder-2/folder-b/folder-y

bucket-a/folder-3/folder-c/folder-z

I'd like to copy all files landing in bucket-a/folder-2/folder-b and all its sub-directories.

But NOT copy any files that land in either folder-1, folder-3 or any of their sub-directories.

Just not sure where or how to introduce an 'if' argument into what is already working well.

Here's the code so far:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {
  const storage = new Storage();
  const gcsEvent = event;
  const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
  const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name
  const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 
  const destFileBucket = 'my_dest_bucket'

  storage
  .bucket(sourceFileBucket)
  .file(sourcePathOnly)
  .copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + sourceFolder[1])); 

};
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

---

This is the current code which is giving me the sourcePathOnly not defined error and also creates the two folders, folder-2 & folder-b at the root:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const storage = new Storage()


  // Process only if it's in the correct folder
  if (sourcePathOnly.indexOf('folder-2/folder-b') > -1) {

    const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name
    const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 
    const destFileBucket = 'my_dest_bucket'

    storage
    .bucket(sourceFileBucket)
    .file(sourcePathOnly)
    .copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + 
    sourceFolder[1])); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Storage and event on Cloud Storage are very powerful. But, you can't set filter on which condition the event is trigger.

By the way, you have to set a "manual filter" in your code

```
exports.helloGCS = (event, context) => {
  const gcsEvent = event;
  const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name

  // Process only if it's in the correct folder
  if (sourcePathOnly.indexOf('folder-2/folder-b') > -1) {
    const storage = new Storage();
    const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 
    const destFileBucket = 'my_dest_bucket'

    storage
    .bucket(sourceFileBucket)
    .file(sourcePathOnly)
    .copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + 
    sourceFolder[1])); 
  }
}
```

Now you only process the file coming from the src path that you want.

The bad things is that your function will be trigger on each file created in the bucket, and thus your function will start, perform the check and exit. You will billed 100ms of processing for just doing nothing. *I already open a feature request on this topic.*

Comment: That's great thanks Guillaume. Unfortunately getting a "Error: function execution failed. Details:
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" message.

Comment: Lets hope they implement your  feature request. In the meantime it hopefully shouldn't be a huge number of files.

Comment: ... I looked up the cost of invoking a Cloud Function ... it appears to be about $0.40 per million invocations.  That's about 2.5 million new files per dollar.

Comment: Yes the limit is high, and there is 2M free per month per project. But I don't know the other invocation that you have beside, but this increase the number of invocation and the CPU/Memory consumption on the project per month and you reach quicked the billing limit (above the free tiers)

Comment: About the code, I don't understand why there is an issue with split. I didn't change this part, I simply added a if and move some line with a copy-paste. Did you double check your code?

Comment: I've rectified one typo (sorry) however I am getting an error message that "ReferenceError: sourcePathOnly is not defined at exports.helloGCS" .                                   it creates the two folders ( folder-2  & folder-b ) but in parallel i.e. next to each other in the destination bucket rather than folder-b inside of folder-2. the file itself isn't copied. no doubt because it can't find folder-2/folder-b to write it to in the destination bucket?

Comment: Because of your error, you must have a side effect. Fix the `sourcePathOnly`, if it's not define, that means you have a difference between the definition `const sourcePathOnly...` and the usage.

Comment: No the code looks OK and works well if I remove the IF line: if (sourcePathOnly.indexOf('folder-2/folder-b') > -1) {

Comment: I initially forgot the closing brace in my post.

Comment: yeah I picked that up, so it's not that.

Comment: Just to clarify yes I had picked that closing brace but I still dont really know why the extra IF argument breaks the sourcePathOnly.

Comment: Yes, it's nor normal. the if only compare the value, not change them, that's why I asked you about typo error, something different. In any case, I tested this code before publishing it, and it worked on my side.

Comment: mmm... I'm not going mad? This is the code I have and the only thing I've changed is 'my_dest_bucket'  :

Comment: and more of the error message: ReferenceError: sourcePathOnly is not defined at exports.helloGCS (/srv/functions/index.js:9:3) at Promise.resolve.then (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:330:28) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Comment: Doh! Not sure why I didn't spot it earlier but shouldn't this line in your code:   "const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) "  be defined before and outside the IF argument?

Comment: No, before the IF you need all the data required for performing the IF. Indeed, in case of FALSE evaluation of the IF, you didn't have to perform the processing of the TRUE case.

Comment: Ah sorry I hadn't noticed you'd had changed your code in the meantime to have the sourcePathOnly before the IF

Comment: OK half works but it only copies some of the total files that it should copy. I also get a "could not load default authentication credentials" error despite all the files created equal. It looks like all the files trigger the function but not all get written to the destination bucket.

Comment: Looks like it can handle 4 files and any more than that it causes the credential error. Any ideas?

Comment: OK thanks Guillaume. worked out it was because I had the online bucket UI open. When closed and only the function is accessing the buckets there is no error. Another two questions if your're interested: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58934727/copy-whole-source-folder-rather-than-just-the-trigger-file-using-google-function) & [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932972/error-when-trying-to-count-number-of-files-in-a-specific-directory-using-event-d)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere You said, "I already open a feature request on this topic." Do you have the link to it?

Answer (score 0):

A bucket doesn't work exactly like a file system, you can check Google Cloud Storage structure and hierarchy information at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork).

In order to be able to filter how you specified you need I would recommend you to list all the objects in the bucket and then filter those you need from the folders you want.

When you store something in a bucket the format would be like this:

> gsutil will make a bucket listing request for the named bucket, using delimiter="/" and prefix="abc". It will then examine the bucket listing results and determine whether there are objects in the bucket whose path starts with gs://your-bucket/abc/, to determine whether to treat the target as an object name or a directory name. In turn this impacts the name of the object you create: If the above check indicates there is an "abc" directory you will end up with the object gs://your-bucket/abc/your-file; otherwise you will end up with the object gs://your-bucket/abc.

Hope this helps you out. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the link Stefan.