# Error when trying to count number of files in a specific directory using event driven Google Cloud Functions Node JS 10

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I get the following error when using file.length in a Google Function using Node JS 10:

> textPayload: "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument
>   must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object"

My current code is as follows:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

var fs = require('fs'); 

exports.copyRenders = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 

fs.readdir(sourceFolder, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
  //console.log(`Files are: ${sourceFolder}`);  

});
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `.join("")` to make your `sourceFolder` constant a **String**, it seems to me you made it an **Array** with `.slice`

```js
exports.copyRenders = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2)
      .join("") // <- here 

    fs.readdir(sourceFolder, (err, files) => {
      //console.log(files.length);
      console.log(`Files are: ${sourceFolder}`);  
    });
}
```

Comment: Really sorry Gui3 I had commented out the wrong line. tried your solution but I still get the same error.

Comment: I really don't know about GCS so I may have replied too fast, but I had the intuition that the error came from this line `fs.readdir(sourceFolder...)` ... check what **sourceFolder** contains and if it is readable by the fs.readdir ?

Comment: I think you have to add `/` in the `join`, else you don't build a valid path (folder name are appended without separator)

Answer (score 0):

In Cloud Storage there are no folders [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) It is explained how directories work, as they are only a longer names for the objects that include directory/subdirectory/objectName.

Therefor the usual ways to get all the elements in a directory doesn't work, [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) is an example of listing objects on a bucket and the way to list object that share a prefix (that are on the same directory).

Here is how you can get the number of files that share a prefix on a bucket.

```
async function countFilesByPrefix(bucketName, prefix) {
  // [START storage_list_files_with_prefix]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();

  const options = {
    prefix: prefix,
  };

  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles(options);
  console.log(`  Number of Files ${ files.length}`);

}
```