# Copy whole source folder rather than just the trigger file using Google Functions & Node JS 10

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Need to tweak the following code so it copies the whole of `sourceFolder` instead of just the event file itself  but not sure how to do this.

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

exports.copyRenders = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name



    const folderToWatch = ' ... folder on source bucket... '


// Process only if it's in the correct folder
  if (sourcePathOnly.indexOf(folderToWatch) > -1) {

    const storage = new Storage();
    const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 
    const destFileBucket = 'trans-test'

    storage
    .bucket(sourceFileBucket)
    .file(sourcePathOnly)
    .copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + 
    sourceFolder[1])); 
  }
  console.log(`Processing file: ${sourcePathOnly}`);  
}
```

With new code from answer bellow:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const {path} = require('path');

exports.copyRenders = (event, context) => {
    const gcsEvent = event;
    const sourcePathOnly = gcsEvent.name



    const folderToWatch = ' ... folder on source bucket... '


// Process only if it's in the correct folder
  if (sourcePathOnly.indexOf(folderToWatch) > -1) {

    const storage = new Storage();
    const sourceFileBucket = gcsEvent.bucket
    const sourceFolder = sourcePathOnly.split('/').slice(-2) 
    const destFileBucket = 'trans-test'

    const options = {
        // Get the source path without the file name)
        prefix: sourcePathOnly.slice(0,sourcePathOnly.lastIndexOf("/")),
    };

    const [files] = storage.bucket(sourceFileBucket).getFiles(options);

    files.forEach(file => {
        file.copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + sourceFolder[1]));
        });
    }
    console.log(`Processing file: ${sourcePathOnly}`);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`getFiles()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getFiles) to build a list of files in your directory, and then copy the files. Something like this (you may have to modify for your scenario):

```js
const [ files ] = await storage.bucket(sourceFileBucket).getFiles({
  autoPaginate: false,
  prefix: sourceFolder
});

files.forEach(file => file.copy( ... ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Travis. Having the following error with await : "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: You can also send a callback into `getFiles` per the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all the file of a directory prefix

```
const options = {
    // Get the source path without the file name)
    prefix: sourcePathOnly.slice(0,sourcePathOnly.lastIndexOf("/")),
  };

const [files] = storage.bucket(sourceFileBucket).getFiles(options);

files.forEach(file => {
    file.copy(storage.bucket(destFileBucket).file(sourceFolder[0] + '/' + 
    sourceFolder[1]));
});
```

Be careful, each time that your function will be trigger, the whole prefix matches will be copied. And if you copy in the same bucket, you can create an exponential infinite loop!

*Note: mathematically, I'm not know if something infinite can be exponential!!*

Comment: Sorry if this is a real noob question Guillaume but searched around and all results point to azure, just cant get a handle on how to "copy blob". Do I need to define 'blob' ?

Comment: I'm totally ashamed. I answered you in Python and not in NodeJS. I updated my answer. Again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Haha, phew I thought I was going mad. Thanks Guilluame. I think I'm not adding it to the original code correctly. Would mind looking at the amended version in my original question and checking I am indeed putting it in the right place?

Comment: Thanks Guilluame, Just tried it but still getting the error: textPayload: "TypeError: Storage is not a constructor.  I'll have a look tomorrow when I have a bit more time and let you know.

Comment: Package file had reverted back so just updated it and not getting the storage error anymore. I am getting the following error though but not sure where the issue is?  textPayload: "TypeError: storage.bucket(...).getFiles is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: Can you perform a `console.log(storage.bucket(sourceFileBucket).getFiles(options))` just before the current line where you perform the `getFiles()`. If the function exists and if the return isn't an iterable, it's maybe because the return is empty! Check the log value.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, just tried that and unfortunately still getting: TypeError: storage.bucket(...).getFiles is not a function or its return value is not iterable at exports.copyRender